# Ubuntu files on different drives and disk space requirements?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive, ssd

I have a SSD and a HDD on my system. I want to install Ubuntu on the SSD (dual boot with win10) and keep all other files, programs etc. on the HDD? How much disk space I need on the SSD and how can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) and [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 0):

The official "minimum" space requirements for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS & Ubuntu 17.10 show 25GB of free hard drive space. You probably will want to add some cushion to that so that you don't run into trouble with your SSD -- especially since both Ubuntu and Win10 will increase in size.

Assuming you have 25GB free on the SSD plus some cushion (I'd recommend ~40GB+ free space on the SSD before moving forward), then when you [boot to an Ubuntu Live USB stick](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) and step through the installation process, you'll have the opportunity to make choices about where everything gets installed and how.

Comment: Thanks for the information but maybe I couldn't express myself clearly. Can I add 'cushions' to my HDD and run Ubuntu with 25GB on the SSD for faster boots? Since my SDD is 128 GB I can not have a 40+ GB partition

Comment: You will probably want more than 25GB of free space on the SSD to install and run Ubuntu there for fast booting of a "typical" desktop installation of Ubuntu. If you'd like to avoid having to set up a partition as large as the one I recommended, you can [refer to the article linked in a previous comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar) by @karel to see if a different Ubuntu configuration makes sense. Of course you can try a 25GB partition at first if that's all you have. It should work for a while.